# Detecting getView() call completed.

Tags: android, adapter

I have been searching about any call back method that is called when last getView() has completed its execution, or I may say all item in the AdapterView are drawn/laid.

I found there isn't any specific android api Method that acts as a call back method.

Please guys help me finding a way, How can we detect the call to last getView() for a particular data source list.

Comment: Why do you need to know that?

Comment: Because once the getView() has completed drawing the visible view, I want some relevant tasks to be started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no last getView()

When you are scrolling in a list, for each item that will become visible an `getView` will be called. EVEN when it has already been on screen.

So if you want to know if each item in a `ListView` has been visible, you have to count for your self :).

Comment: But say there are 10 item out of which 4 are should, getView() will be called 4times or more but only for this 4 visible items. Can I detect the last time getView() is called for this set of visible items, i.e., the 4th item

Comment: Ah, you want to know when the last getView is called from the 
visible items. Hmm, not possible AFAIK. Why do you need to know this?

Comment: Because once the getView() has completed drawing the visible view, I want some relevant tasks to be started.

Answer (score 0):

This is because it is always being called. What happens is `getView()` is called every time you scroll the `ListView`. When an item is poped outside the `ListView` (not visible to the user) it is passed as a recycled view (`convertView`) to `getView()` to fill it with data that will be the new item that will be poped in from the other side of the scroll. You also cannot predict this action as as the number of visible items in the `ListView` will varry depending on the screen size. You can override `getView()` and check at which point you need to trigger your action.